# How to hide multiple columns in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using 4 sequential columns from sheet 1 to generate charts in sheet 2. I want to hide those 4 columns in sheet 1.

I've tried the below code to hide the columns:

```
Set allColumns = dataSheet.Columns("J:M")
allColumns.Hidden = True
```

Comment: *dataSheet* needs to be defined as the object (not in the code you've displayed).  Beyond that, the code works for me.  The error was a run-time 424 when i ran your code as is (2 lines) which states an object is required.

Answer (score 1):

## Constants and References

```
Sub AllCol()

  Const cVntSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"   ' Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cStrRange As String = "J:M"       ' Range Address

  Dim dataSheet As Worksheet              ' Worksheet

  ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
  Set dataSheet = Worksheets(cVntSheet)

  ' Hide the range.
  dataSheet.Columns(cStrRange).Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap `Sheet1` with your actual sheet name.

```
Sub HideMe()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("J:M").Hidden = True

End Sub
```

---

Notice this can be done in one line. If you want to use variables (workbook or worksheets), they should build the above string when combined

Something like:

```
Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim hm as String: hm = "J:M"

ws.Columns(hm).Hidden = True
```

If you substitute your variables into the last line, you will end up with the exact same line of code shown in the first sub.